# Oracle Data Pump: special characters in schema name + bash variable substitution

Tags: bash, oracle, datapump, expdp

I have a bash function that does a schema export with `expdp`. That works great in the 90% of the cases but if the schema name contains minus (`-`) character then it fails with the following oracle error:

```
Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 09:43:50 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression 'abc-def' does not correspond to any schemas.
```

According to docs the minus character is considered as a special characters and I need to escape them on the following way: `'\"abc-def\"'`.

Unfortunately this pattern does not work for me. Another problem is that I use a bash variable to pass the schema name to `expdp` and if I escape everything then the bash variable substitution does not work.

What is the proper way to escape special chars in the DB schema name for `expdp` and keep the bash variable substitution ability too?

This is my bash function:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# execute a datapump export
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function exportSchema {
    local schema oracleHost oraclePort dumpFile
    schema="$1"
    oracleHost="localhost"
    oraclePort=1521
    dumpFile="$schema"-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d.%Hh.%Mm.%Ss')

    printf "\nexporting to a dump file...\n"
    printf "    database host:         %s\n" "$oracleHost"
    printf "    database port:         %s\n" "$oraclePort"
    printf "    pluggable database:    %s\n" "$ORACLE_PDB"
    printf "    datapump user:         %s\n" "$DATAPUMP_USER"
    printf "    datapump password:     %s\n" "$DATAPUMP_PASSWORD"
    printf "    schema to be exported: %s\n" "$schema"
    printf "    dump file name:        %s.dmp\n" "$dumpFile"

    expdp "$DATAPUMP_USER"/"$DATAPUMP_PASSWORD"@"$oracleHost":"$oraclePort"/"$ORACLE_PDB" schemas="$schema" directory=DATAPUMP_WORKSPACE dumpfile="$dumpFile.dmp" logfile="$dumpFile.log"
    exitCode=$?
    if [ $exitCode -ne 0 ]; then
        printf "ERROR: An unexpected error has occurred while exporting the '%s' schema.\n" "$schema"
    else
        printf "OK: The '%s' schema has been successfully exported.\n" "$schema"
    fi
}
```

**I have tried the followings, but non of them work fine:**

- `schemas="$schema"`
- `schemas= '\"$schema\"'`
- `schemas= "\"$schema\"'`
- `schemas="abc-def"`
- `schemas="abc\-def"`
- `schemas='"abc-def"'`
- `schemas='"abc\-def"'`
- `schemas="'abc-def'"`
- `schemas="'abc\-def'"`

**This command works properly:**

```
sqlplus abc-def/password@10.178.146.33:1521/ORCLPDB1 

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 12:15:28 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Oct 10 2023 12:14:58 +00:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

I have no more idea why `expdp` does not like my schema name but `sqlplus` can connect to the schema.

**-- UPDATE --**

I am calling the function this way:

```
exportSchema  "xxx_yyy"
exportSchema  "abc-def"
exportSchema  '\"abc-def\"'
exportSchema  '\\"abc-def\\"'
```

**The 1st call runs properly:**

```
$ export.sh

exporting schema to a dump file...
    database host:         localhost
    database port:         1521
    pluggable database:    ORCLPDB1
    datapump user:         datapump
    datapump password:     password
    schema to be exported: xxx_yyy
    dump file name:        xxx_yyy-2023-10-10.13h.44m.14s.dmp

Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 13:44:14 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "DATAPUMP"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  datapump/********@localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1 schemas=xxx_yyy directory=DATAPUMP_WORKSPACE dumpfile=xxx_yyy-2023-10-10.13h.44m.14s.dmp logfile=xxx_yyy-2023-10-10.13h.44m.14s.log 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
...
```

**Unfortunately the rest are failing:**

```
exporting schema to a dump file...
    database host:         localhost
    database port:         1521
    pluggable database:    ORCLPDB1
    datapump user:         datapump
    datapump password:     password
    schema to be exported: abc-def
    dump file name:        abc-def-2023-10-10.13h.53m.54s.dmp

Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 13:53:54 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression 'abc-def' does not correspond to any schemas.

ERROR: An unexpected error has occurred while exporting the 'abc-def' schema.

exporting schema to a dump file...
    database host:         localhost
    database port:         1521
    pluggable database:    ORCLPDB1
    datapump user:         datapump
    datapump password:     password
    schema to be exported: \"abc-def\"
    dump file name:        \"abc-def\"-2023-10-10.13h.54m.01s.dmp

Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 13:54:01 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression 'abc-def' does not correspond to any schemas.

exporting schema to a dump file...
    database host:         localhost
    database port:         1521
    pluggable database:    ORCLPDB1
    datapump user:         datapump
    datapump password:     password
    schema to be exported: \\"abc-def\\"
    dump file name:        \\"abc-def\\"-2023-10-10.13h.59m.17s.dmp

Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 10 13:59:17 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression '\"abc-def\"' does not correspond to any schemas.
```

This makes me crazy...

Comment: As you're quoting it, does your schema value match the case of the schema name in the data dictionary?

Comment: how exportSchema function is called, it should be ok with `exportSchema '\"abc-def\"' ...` note the signle quote here are syntactical (bash syntax), the string value is `\"abc-def\"`

Comment: Could you please check my update?

Comment: Maybe try to put all these params into a parfile and use it